# Got stuck at 'make runtest' while installing Caffe caused by HDF5 lib

Tags: anaconda, hdf5, caffe

I want to install Caffe on CentOS 7, but got stuck at 'make runtest'. one warning like
***Warning! HDF5 library version mismatched error***
And the abortion code followd as

```html
SIGABRT (@0xc8b) received by PID 3211 (TID 0x7fcfd38c29c0) from PID 3211; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fcfcede5100 (unknown)
    @     0x7fcfcea4a5f7 __GI_raise
    @     0x7fcfcea4bce8 __GI_abort
    @     0x7fcfd26c0592 H5check_version
    @     0x7fcfcf6e2630 caffe::HDF5DataLayer<>::LoadHDF5FileData()
    @     0x7fcfcf6e1518 caffe::HDF5DataLayer<>::LayerSetUp()
    @     0x7fcfcf7f5ecc caffe::Net<>::Init()
    @     0x7fcfcf7f6d55 caffe::Net<>::Net()
    @     0x7fcfcf6af93a caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
    @     0x7fcfcf6b0a3c caffe::Solver<>::Init()
    @     0x7fcfcf6b0d6a caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
    @           0x49e598 caffe::AdaGradSolverTest<>::InitSolver()
    @           0x49fc40 caffe::GradientBasedSolverTest<>::InitSolverFromProtoString()
    @           0x4942a4 caffe::GradientBasedSolverTest<>::RunLeastSquaresSolver()
    @           0x498c72 caffe::GradientBasedSolverTest<>::TestLeastSquaresUpdate()
    @           0x6f7923 testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
    @           0x6ef6c7 testing::Test::Run()
    @           0x6ef76e testing::TestInfo::Run()
    @           0x6ef875 testing::TestCase::Run()
    @           0x6f1b08 testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests()
    @           0x6f1d97 testing::UnitTest::Run()
    @           0x459d62 main
    @     0x7fcfcea36b15 __libc_start_main
    @           0x460ef9 (unknown)
make: *** [runtest] Aborted
```

I use anaconda to manage the libs, and the version of hdf5 library is 1.8.16. How can i get over this problem? Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the requirement for the HDF5 library version the Caffe installation requires.  I think you will find it is different than the version you have installed on your system.

Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error***
The HDF5 header files used to compile this application do not match
the version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked.  Data corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application continues.  This can happen when an application was compiled by one version of HDF5 but linked with a different version of static or shared HDF5 library.

You should recompile the application or check your shared library related settings such as 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'. You can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment
variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'.
Setting it to 2 or higher will suppress the warning messages totally.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I'vs solved the problem! First, i use 'rpm -qa | grep hdf5' to check the hdf5 versions, and uninstall the lower version; then i 'make clean' caffe, recompile the caffe source. Done! Thank u!